# Accessing an object property in an array of objects Angular 9

Tags: angular

I'm working on an application in Angular 9.  While I would be much more comfortable using something else, the boss' buzzword of the month is Angular so here we are.

I have a very complex object of which I am trying to display pieces of the data.  An example of a similar object would be something like this (because of the subject matter of the actual application, I cannot copy the exact code here):

```
export class Student {

    constructor( 
       public StudentInfo?: StudentInformation,
       public Classes?: ClassInformation[],
       public Books?: BookInformation[],
       ...
       ...
       public ClassesAndBooks?: ClassBookSorter[]
    ) { }

export class StudentInformation {

    constructor( 
       public Name?: string,
       public DOB?: string, 
       public Address?: string,       
    ) { }

export class ClassInformation {

    constructor( 
       public ID?: string,
       public Name?: string, 
       public Teacher?: string,       
    ) { }

export class BookInformation {

    constructor( 
       public ID: string,
       public ClassID: string,
       public Title?: string, 
       public Price?: string,       
    ) { }

export class ClassesAndBooks {

    constructor( 
       public Class?: ClassInformation,
       public Books?: BookInformation[],       
    ) { }
```

So I'm trying to list out the classes with their associated books on the page. When I do this:

```
<mat-tab label="Classes And Books">
          <div *ngFor="let gclass of StuInfo.ClassesAndBooks" >
            <div class="card m-2 p-1 text-center" style="border: 2px solid black">
              <div class="col">
                <label>Class Name:  </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </mat-tab>
```

I get one line per class so I know the data is there.  When I do this:

```
<mat-tab label="Classes And Books">
          <div *ngFor="let gclass of StuInfo.ClassesAndBooks" >
            <div class="card m-2 p-1 text-center" style="border: 2px solid black">
              <div class="col">
                <label>Class Name: {{ gclass.Class.Name }}  </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </mat-tab>
```

Nothing shows up.  The error that shows in the developer window is: gclass_r18.Class is undefined

I'm receiving the all the data from a service with the exception of the ClassesAndBooks. That I build on the fly in the constructor so if there is a way to group the books and classes on the fly with a ngFor or something, I'm open.

**Edited to Add**

Here you are John Graham.

```
ClassesAndBooks: (2) […]
​​
Class: Object { ID: "M101", Name: "Basic Math", Teacher: "Prof. X"}
​​​
Books: Array []
​​​
Class: Object { ID: "M102", Name: "More Basic Math", Teacher: "Prof Why"}
​​​
Books: (2) […]
​​​​
0: Object { ID: "2945789", ClassID: "M102", Title: "Don't Sleep in Class", Price: "40"}
​​​​
1: Object { ID: "8675309", ClassID: "M102", Title: "Math Facts", Price: "200" }
```

Comment: Can you show us your component.ts code? Or if not could you log out the `StuInfo.ClassesAndBooks` after you retrieve it so we can see what that object looks like when populated?

Answer (score 0):

So when thinking smart doesn't work you think stupid.  I went back and re-entered the code and it is working now.  I can only assume I had fat fingered something and it was corrected when I retyped it.